# Get JsonOptions from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I set to indent JSON in Startup class, but how do I retrieve the formatting value from a controller?

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc()
                .AddWebApiConventions()
                .AddJsonOptions(options=> options.SerializerSettings.Formatting=Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    }

}


public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public bool GetIsIndented()
    {
        bool isIndented = ????
        return isIndented;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just inject an instance of `IOptions<MvcJsonOptions>` into your Controller, like so:

```
private readonly MvcJsonOptions _jsonOptions;

public HomeController(IOptions<MvcJsonOptions> jsonOptions, /* ... */)
{
    _jsonOptions = jsonOptions.Value;
}

// ...

public bool GetIsIdented() =>
    _jsonOptions.SerializerSettings.Formatting == Formatting.Indented;
```

See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.1) for more information about `IOptions` (the Options pattern).

If all you care about is the `Formatting`, you can simplify slightly and just use a `bool` field, like so:

```
private readonly bool _isIndented;

public HomeController(IOptions<MvcJsonOptions> jsonOptions, /* ... */)
{
    _isIndented = jsonOptions.Value.SerializerSettings.Formatting == Formatting.Indented;
}
```

In this example, there's no need for the `GetIsIndented` function.

Comment: For the record, a constructor can have multiple IOptions<T> parameters.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a class where you declare the current configuration values

```
public class MvcConfig
{
    public Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting Formatting { get; set; }
}
```

Then instantiate it in the configure method where you also register the class as a singleton

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var mvcConfig = new MvcConfig
    {
        Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented
    };

    services.AddMvc()
            .AddWebApiConventions()
            .AddJsonOptions(options=> options.SerializerSettings.Formatting=mvcConfig.Formatting);

    services.AddSingleton(mvcConfig);
}
```

Then inject it in the controller and use it

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly MvcConfig _mvcConfig;
    public HomeController(MvcConfig mvcConfig)
    {
        _mvcConfig = mvcConfig;
    }
    public bool GetIsIndented()
    {
        return _mvcConfig.Formatting == Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
    }
}
```

Comment: If my constructor of the controller already takes a WhateverConfig, can the constructor accept two options, like `public HomeController(WhateverConfig wc, MvcConfig mvcConfig)`?